# How to convert list of list to simple list by removing duplicate values using scala?

Tags: list, scala, collections

I have following list -

```
List(List(
List(((groupName,group1),(tagMember,["192.168.20.30","192.168.20.20","192.168.20.21"]))), 
List(((groupName,group1),(tagMember,["192.168.20.30"]))),
List(((groupName,group1),(tagMember,["192.168.20.30","192.168.20.20"])))))
```

I want to convert it to -

```
List((groupName, group1),(tagMember,["192.168.20.30","192.168.20.20","192.168.20.21"]))
```

I tried to use .flatten but unable to form desired output.

How do I get above mentioned output using scala??

Comment: Can you simplify your example into some code we can copy into a repl? And maybe use shorter strings?

Comment: I used list.flatten to remove flatten list but have no idea how to merge list by removing duplicate elements

Comment: @Vishwas: `ll.flatten.distinct`

Comment: Is the IP address the only variable part in the list, or could there be other entries in the list like (groupName, group2)?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a valid Scala code.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make some changes to your input to make it valid.

Input List:

```
   val ll = List(List(
      List((("groupName","group1"),("tagMember", List("192.168.20.30","192.168.20.20","192.168.20.21")))),
      List((("groupName","group1"),("tagMember",List("192.168.20.30")))),
      List((("groupName","group1"),("tagMember",List("192.168.20.30","192.168.20.20"))))
    ))
```

Code below works if the group, and tagMember are the same across all the elements in the list

```
  def getUniqueIpsConstantGroupTagMember(inputList:  List[List[List[((String, String), (String, List[String]))]]]) = {
      // List[((String, String), (String, List[String]))]
      val flattenedList  = ll.flatten.flatten

      if (flattenedList.size > 0) {
         val group = flattenedList(0)._1
         val tagMember = flattenedList(0)._2._1
         val ips = flattenedList flatMap (_._2._2)

         ((group), (tagMember, ips.distinct))
      } 
         else List()
  }

  println(getUniqueIpsConstantGroupTagMember(ll))
```

Output:

```
((groupName,group1),(tagMember,List(192.168.20.30, 192.168.20.20, 192.168.20.21)))
```

Now, let's assume you could have different groupNames.

Sample input:

```
  val listWithVariableGroups = List(List(
      List((("groupName","group1"),("tagMember",List("192.168.20.30","192.168.20.20","192.168.20.21")))),
      List((("groupName","group1"),("tagMember",List("192.168.20.30")))),
      List((("groupName","group1"),("tagMember",List("192.168.20.30","192.168.20.20")))),
      List((("groupName","group2"),("tagMember",List("192.168.20.30","192.168.20.10"))))   
    ))
```

The following code should work.

```
  def getUniqueIpsForMultipleGroups(inputList:  List[List[List[((String, String), (String, List[String]))]]]) = {
    val flattenedList = inputList.flatten.flatten

    // Map[(String, String),List[(String, List[String])]]
    val groupedByGroupNameId = flattenedList.groupBy(p => p._1) map {
      case (key, value) => (key, ("tagMember", extractUniqueTagIps(value)))
    }
    groupedByGroupNameId
  }

  def extractUniqueTagIps(list: List[((String, String), (String, List[String]))]) = {
    val ips = list flatMap (_._2._2)
    ips.distinct
  }

  getUniqueIpsForMultipleGroups(listWithVariableGroups).foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
((groupName,group1),(tagMember,List(192.168.20.30, 192.168.20.20, 192.168.20.21)))
((groupName,group2),(tagMember,List(192.168.20.30, 192.168.20.10)))
```